# How to setup position with FEN string in stockfish.js?

Tags: javascript

I want to make a chess puzzle on my website for my student.
I use stockfish.js to play with the engine.
How to change the start position on the board?
I try to change all FEN string but did not work.
Where to look for the function or something?
Anybody can help me, please?

Answer (score 3):

Interacting with the javascript port of Stockfish is (at time of writing) still like communicating with a chess engine that uses/supports UCI (Universal Chess Interface).

The UCI `position` command should suffice:

```js
   var fenString = "rnbqkbnr/ppppp1pp/8/5p2/3P4/8/PPP1PPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 2"
   // start UCI
   stockfish.postMessage("uci");
   // start new game
   stockfish.postMessage("ucinewgame");
   // set new game position
   stockfish.postMessage("position fen " + fenString);
   // start search
   stockfish.postMessage("go depth 10");
```

Edited: Updated case for postMessage() function.

Comment: Thx, can you tell me where to modify? which file?

Comment: You add this modification in the same place you initialise stockfish. { var stockfish = new Worker('stockfish.js'); ... }

Comment: Hi, I tried everything but I don't understand how it works. I use https://github.com/nmrugg/stockfish.js/  and I added to index.html this line  var stockfish = new Worker("stockfish.js");
          var fenString = "rnbqkbnr/ppp1pppp/8/8/2pP4/8/PP2PPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 3"
          // start UCI
          stockfish.postMessage("uci");
          // start new game
          stockfish.postMessage("ucinewgame");
          // set new game position
          stockfish.postMessage("position fen " + fenString);
          // start search
          stockfish.postMessage("go depth 10");

Comment: Try the Stockfish.js from https://github.com/niklasf/stockfish.js

Comment: But how to use in index.html?

Comment: Using stockfish.js with your index.html will require you add an interface.  Maybe https://github.com/exoticorn/stockfish-js/tree/master/example as an example may help?

Comment: Thanks. remember that postMessage is correct not postmessage. it's case sensitive

Answer (score 0):

I was working on the same thing and figured it out -- it's by no means obvious and within the stockfish example there are lots of little trips and pitfalls. I found a couple questions online and thought I'd give them some answers.

So -- this answer assumes working with the example code found here: https://github.com/nmrugg/stockfish.js/tree/Stockfish11/example.

There are two major modifications that need to happen - first in the `index.html` file and second in `enginegame.js`.

First we'll define a helper function which will make it easy to work with the url "search" as it's called:

```js
function searchToObject() {      
  var pairs = window.location.search.substring(1).split("&"),      
    obj = {},      
    pair,      
    i;      
            
  for ( i in pairs ) {      
    if ( pairs[i] === "" ) continue;      
          
    pair = pairs[i].split("=");      
    obj[ decodeURIComponent( pair[0] ) ] = decodeURIComponent( pair[1] );      
  }      
          
  return obj;      
}
```

For ease I just placed that function in both files, within `index.html` it's at the beginning of the script tag, in `enginegame.js` it's the very first line. Also btw, I certainly pilfered that from stackoverflow, but I can't seem to find that answer any more, rats.

In `index.html` the `newGame` function wants to look like this:

```js
newGame = function newGame() {        
  var baseTime = parseFloat($('#timeBase').val()) * 60;        
  var inc = parseFloat($('#timeInc').val());        
  var skill = parseInt($('#skillLevel').val());        
 
  game.reset();        
 
  let search = searchToObject();        
 
  if (search.player) {        
    game.setPlayerColor(search.player)        
  } else {        
    game.setPlayerColor($('#color-white').hasClass('active') ? 'white' : 'black');        
  }        
 
  if (search.fen) {        
    game.game.load(search.fen);        
    game.board.position(game.game.fen());        
  }        
 
  game.setTime(baseTime, inc);        
  game.setSkillLevel(skill);        
  game.setDisplayScore($('#showScore').is(':checked'));        
 
  game.start();        
}
```

Note the game.game and game.board -- those need to be added in `enginegame.js` where it's returning an object. If I were writing this I would have done it differently, but I didn't have the patience to rename things.

Next up in `enginegame.js` we need to adjust `prepareMove`.

```js
function prepareMove() {    
    stopClock();    
    $('#pgn').text(game.pgn());    
    board.position(game.fen());    
    updateClock();    
    var turn = game.turn() == 'w' ? 'white' : 'black';    
    if (!game.game_over()) {    
        if (turn != playerColor) {    
            let search = searchToObject();    
            if (search.fen) {    
                uciCmd('position fen ' + search.fen + ' moves ' + get_moves());    
            } else {    
                uciCmd('position startpos moves' + get_moves());    
                uciCmd('position startpos moves' + get_moves(), evaler);    
            }    
            evaluation_el.textContent = "";    
            uciCmd("eval", evaler);    
 
            if (time && time.wtime) {    
                uciCmd("go " + (time.depth ? "depth " + time.depth : "") + " wtime " + time.wtime + " winc " + time.winc + " btime " + time.btime + " binc " + time.binc);    
            } else {    
                uciCmd("go " + (time.depth ? "depth " + time.depth : ""));    
            }    
            isEngineRunning = true;    
        }    
        if (game.history().length >= 2 && !time.depth && !time.nodes) {    
            startClock();    
        }    
    }    
}
```

See, the trick is that if ever there was a fen string to start the game, **every subsequent `position` call needs to be different**. I think that's probably what's tripping most people up - that's definitely what got me.

What helped things click for me was reading through [the UCI documentation](https://gist.github.com/aliostad/f4470274f39d29b788c1b09519e67372). Before that my board was in some crazy infinite loop.

Also one weird but critical bit I stumbled onto was the `game.game.load(<fen string>)` function call in the `index.html` file. I can't find any documentation for that. I don't even remember how I found it. But there it is!